# Can R matrix multiplication be optimised when the result will be symmetrical?

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I need to take the inner product of every pair of columns in a particular matrix, which I achieve by calculating

```
t(M) %*% M
```

However this naturally produces a symmetrical result, doing just over twice the necessary work (I don't need the diagonal either). Obviously I could break the multiply down into individual inner product operations, but is there a better way to calculate just the upper triangular part of the product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description in `help("crossprod")`:

> Given matrices x and y as arguments, return a matrix cross-product.
>   This is formally equivalent to (but usually slightly faster than) the
>   call `t(x) %*% y` (crossprod) or `x %*% t(y)` (tcrossprod).

Thus, use `crossprod(M)`.

Comment: *facepalm* Dunno how I missed that :) Thanks!